# A conjecture about a smothness concerning consecutive primes

Tags: number-theory, inequality, prime-numbers, divisibility, conjectures

This is a conjecture inspired by the relative but piecewise smoothness of the sequence https://oeis.org/A068901/graph?png=1, about the least number $a_n$, such that $n\mid p_n+a_n$, where $p_n$ is the $n$-th prime.

Conjecture:

> $n\mid p_n+a \wedge 0≤a<n \Rightarrow \exists b\in\mathbb Z: n+1\mid p_{n+1}+b$,
>   where $|a-b|<2\cdot\sqrt n$.

Are there counter-examples, or can the conjecture be proved? Tested for all primes $p_n<100,000,000$.

---

The conjecture badly describe the real smothness. Making some more experiments lead me to comment my question with an other conjecture:

> As above, given $\varepsilon>0$ there exist 
>   $N$ such that $n>N \Rightarrow |a-b|<\varepsilon\sqrt n$.

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, this is the same as asking that $-p_n\text{ mod }n$ (i.e. the least non-negative residue in that class) is within $2\sqrt{n}$ of some number congruent to $-p_{n+1}$ mod $n+1$?

Comment: @MiloBrandt - Yes that seems correct.

Comment: I *think* this is essentially in the same family as Legendre's conjecture or Andrica's conjecture, perhaps requiring some refinements of the prime number theorem. Note that if we have $kn=p_n+a$ then the minimal $|a-b|$ is going to be $|p_{n+1}-k(n+1)|=|p_{n+1}-p_n-k|$. We note that $k$ is asymptotic to $\log(n)$, so we're basically trying to cap how quickly the quantity $p_m-m\log(m)$ can change for consecutive $m$ in terms of $\sqrt{m}$.